# Problems with struct mapping in C# for strings

Tags: c#, string, struct, structure, marshalling

I'm trying to map a (rather archaic) C++ string message into a C# struct for processing in some new software.  The problem that I am running into is that when mapping the C++ string message into the C# struct I'm losing characters (presumably to the \0 being added).

Message data I need to process looks like this: "91000222201"

```
Where:  "91" is one value
        "0002" is the next value
        "222" is the third value
        "01" is the final value
```

The first struct layout I tried was this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Size = 11, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi), Serializable]
public struct HeaderPacketStruct
{
    [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 2)]
    public string Value1;
    [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 4)]
    public string Value2;
    [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 3)]
    public string Value3;
    [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 2)]
    public string Value4;
}
```

It processed the string ... but resulted in the following values:

```
HeaderPacketStruct.Value1 = "9"
HeaderPacketStruct.Value1 = "000"
HeaderPacketStruct.Value1 = "22"
HeaderPacketStruct.Value1 = "0"
```

When I bumped the SizeConst on each of the strings by +1 (to accommodate for a "\0") it started dropping characters:

```
HeaderPacketStruct.Value1 = "91"
HeaderPacketStruct.Value1 = "0022"
HeaderPacketStruct.Value1 = "01"
HeaderPacketStruct.Value1 = ""
```

It seems like the UnmanagedType.ByValTStr assumes there is a "\0" at the end of the string.  Is there any way around this?

As an aside I was able to get it working with char[] in the below struct.  However, this struct is much harder to work with because each of the values is a char[] and not a string (within the structure).  It would get real painful to have to remap char[] into strings for all the processing.

```
StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Size = 11, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi), Serializable]
public struct HeaderPacketStruct
{
    [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 2)]
    public char[] Value1;
    [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 4)]
    public char[] Value2;
    [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 3)]
    public char[] Value3;
    [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 2)]
    public char[] Value4;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be a lot easier to map it to a single string/char[] field and parse it with some readonly properties?

Comment: There is some where on the order of 40 messages in this interface ... and the majority of them are 70+ fields.  I think it would be a lot easier and maintainable to have dedicated structures that I can map the strings into than parsing each message field by field.

Comment: OK, that is a lot. But so is maintaining 40 of these layout structs. And that last one, with char[], is a direct translation of what you've got as input. I don't think Marshal can do much post-processing. Not its job.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Marshaling in .NET is always buggy. Marshaling of strings is double buggy!

I've made some tests, and the `ByValTStr` expects the last character to be `'\0'` so it reads it and ignores it (but the problem is that it reads it!). You can't even cheat by using `LayoutKind.Explicit`, because it will explode with an error that two fields overlap.

What you can do:

```
[MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 2)]
private char[] value1;

public string Value1
{
    get { return new string(this.value1); }
    set { this.value1 = value.ToCharArray(); }
}
```

This works correctly.

Comment: Ultimatly this is what I did ... it took some time to get all of the getters/setters written ... but it's working like a champ.

Answer (score -2):

Just add correct `FieldOffsetAttribute`s to the case when you added `+1` to SizeConst. And also notice that size of `"91000222201"` string equals 12, not 11.  Try this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Size = 12, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi), Serializable]
public struct HeaderPacketStruct
{
    [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 3), FieldOffset(0)]
    public string Value1;
    [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 5), FieldOffset(2)]
    public string Value2;
    [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 4), FieldOffset(6)]
    public string Value3;
    [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 3), FieldOffset(9)]
    public string Value4;
}
```

Comment: Have you tested it? First you need `LayoutKind.Explicit`, Second I get a `TypeLoadException` because fields overlap.

Comment: No, I have not tested it. I suggested that it should work. If it doesn't then I see just only way - the way you proposed.